# Historical questions: Yes or no?

Tags: discussion, faq, off-topic, site-scope

I recently asked [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5825/why-192-168-for-local-addresses) about the reasoning behind the choice of 192.168 as the standard internal IP block, and a moderator mentioned this:

> I used to think that answering historical questions was a good idea, but I would like to avoid doing this on a regular basis, due to bad help vampire experiences.

Should historical questions be accepted?

Comment: Thank you for raising a meta question.  I have been meaning to ask,  but your question is as good occasion as any.

Comment: No problem at all ;)

Comment: History of network technology might be on topic at the hsm.SE, judging from the responses to this meta question here: http://meta.hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/35/is-history-of-computer-science-on-topic and maybe here as well: http://meta.hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/237/does-hsm-also-include-the-history-of-technology

Answer (score 6):

I want to add to Brett's position on this, which is:

> historical questions are valid as long as there is a way to give a concise, accurate and fact based answer.

We have to draw a line somewhere.  Historical questions, like all others, should *exhibit a compelling reason to be answered* on [NE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).  I could come up with a long list of trivia questions, which meet Brett's criteria above, but the questions are not worth answering.

If the community disagrees with the reasoning in the question, vote to close the historical question as off-topic.

---

#### Examples of fact-based historical questions that are not worth answering on [NE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/)

1. Q: What was the historical reason that ISO standardized on IEEE 802.12 [100VG-AnyLAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100BaseVG)? *(Irrelevant: Nobody uses [100VG-AnyLAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100BaseVG) today)*
2. Q: What was the fastest trasfer rate available over [AUTODIN I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Digital_Network)? *(Trivial & Irrelevant)*
3. Q: Why was [BBN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBN_Technologies) awarded Autonomous System 1? *(Trivial & Irrelevant)*
4. Q: What was the first routing protocol used on ARPANET?
5. Q: `192.168.*.*` is used for many home networks, but it's too hard; I would have chosen something simpler.  What is the historical reason for choosing this address space? *(False Dilemma: The OP can choose something simpler, and we would have to speculate about the reasons for chosing 192.168.0.0/16)*

Comment: I don't get example 5. Essentially he was asking why these specific networks were chosen for RFC1918. I would think that this is worth answering.

Comment: @Sebastian, we don't know why it was chosen in RFC1918, we have to speculate; furthermore the question is founded in the false premise that there isn't something easier to choose.  The OP *can* choose 10/8, and we should not need to speculate in answers

Comment: The OP would choose 1.x.x.x not 10.x.x.x. And at least I was not aware that noone here knows why it was chosen. :) Perhaps someone would know and could answer.

Comment: @Sebastian, the argument that you should choose 1.x.x.x instead of 10.x.x.x/8 is a bit absurd.  10/8 is easy enough, and private address space.  If you're happy with 10/8, then the confusion about 192.168 goes away

Comment: I think the heart of the question was WHY this space was chosen. And if noone can answer that nowadays then perhaps that IS the answer. :)

Comment: We may just wind up agreeing to disagree; the point of my answer here on meta is that some things are trivia, and not worth answering.  My argument is that this question falls into that category.  Note that although I don't think it's on-topic, I didn't unilaterally mod-hammer the question. The question is still open for other answers; in fact, that's why you're now commenting a couple of months later.

Comment: Yeah I think we might. :) I just wanted to provide another perspective. I agree on all the other arguments, just not sure about this one. I saw it coming up on the front page and wanted to chime in. Thanks for not closing it alltogether.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that historical questions are valid here as long as there is a way to give a concise, accurate, and fact based answer.

Many questions about the hows/whys of the early internet are well documented through the many RFCs, as well as through interviews with the primary sources who were involved.

However, there are questions that may not be easily answerable or could be downright opinion based.

I feel that those questions would already be covered for closure under existing standards on being "Too Broad" or "Primarily Opinion Based".

Comment: How would you be able to determine if a historical question had a concise, accurate, fact-based answer prior to asking it, without already knowing what that answer was (in which case you wouldn't be asking, unless you're self-answering)?